# Early-termination foldLeft for Scala Streams

Tags: functional-programming, scala, lazy

The `foldRight` and `foldLeft` methods for Scala `Stream`s cannot terminate early, so here is my attempt to provide that functionality through the "enrich my library" pattern:

```
  implicit class StreamWithLazyFold[A](s: Stream[A]) {
    def foldLeft1[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) => (B, Boolean)): B = s match {
      case _ if s.isEmpty => z
      case h #:: t => {
        val (z1, stop) = f(z, h.asInstanceOf[A])
        if(stop) z1
        else t.asInstanceOf[Stream[A]].foldLeft1(z1)(f)
      }
    }
  }
```

Test:

```
  s.foldLeft1(true)((x, y) => {
    println("run!")
    val b = (y < 3) && x
    (b, !b)
  })
```

It prints "run!" only 3 times.

One question arises immediately: how do I generalize this to all `Seq`s?

All suggestions are welcome, of course.

Answer (score 4):

Your `foldLeft1` method looks fine.

- You don't need `asInstanceOf`. You pattern match a `Stream[A]` so the head will always be `A` and the tail `Stream[A]`.
- A `case` block doesn't need parentheses, but this is mostly a choice of preferred style.

The second `case` block could then look like :

```
case h #:: t => 
  val (z1, stop) = f(z, h)
  if (stop) z1 else t.foldLeft1(z1)(f)
```

---

If we want to generalize your `foldLef1` method, we can see that `foldLeft` is implemented in [`TraversableOnce`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableOnce) for `Stream`, `List`, ... ([source on GitHub](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L153-L157)). So we could create an implicit class for `TraversableOnce`.

We cannot use pattern matching if we are using `TraversableOnce` to get the current element and the rest elements. If we look at the implementation of `foldLeft` for inspiration, we can see that it uses `foreach` and a mutable variable. That is no good in our case since we don't (necessarily) want to loop over all the elements of our collection (or iterator, ...).

We can use `toIterator` to get an `Iterator` to loop over our elements, and with an `Iterator` we can stop iterating whenever we want, that looks just like we want.

We can adjust the code of your `foldLeft1` for `Stream` to use an `Iterator` :

```
implicit class FoldLazy[A](trav: TraversableOnce[A]) {
  def foldLeft1[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) => (B, Boolean)) = {
    def go(it: Iterator[A], z: B): B = 
      if (it.hasNext) {
        val (z1, stop) = f(z, it.next)
        if (stop) z1 else go(it, z1)
      } else z
    go(trav.toIterator, z)
  }
}
```

Which we can use :

```
Stream(1,2,3).foldLeft1(0)((acc, elem) => (acc + elem, elem % 2 == 0))  // 3
List(1,2,3).foldLeft1(0)((acc, elem) => (acc + elem, elem % 2 == 0))    // 3
Vector(1,2,3).foldLeft1(0)((acc, elem) => (acc + elem, elem % 2 == 0))  // 3
```

Note that this doesn't work for `Array`, since `Array` is only a `TraversableOnce` through `ArrayOps` or `WrappedArray`, and the Scala compiler doesn't apply multiple (nested) implicit conversions.

Comment: Nice! Just point that the example would be more clear using `3, 4, 5` which results in `7`. `1, 2, 3` and `3` is confusing. Also, in Scala 2.13 `TraversableOnce` seems deprecated and the suggestion is to replace by `IterableOnce`. `.toIterator` method seems deprecated too, use `.iterator` instead :)